# Call sub function in object with variable brackets

Tags: javascript

```
var myObject = {
    sub: {
        myFunction: function() {
            console.log('check');
        }
    }
}

var callFn = 'sub.myFunction'; // I want it to solve it here, whats going wrong?

myObject[callFn](); // Works, but not with 'sub.myFunction'
myObject.sub.myFunction(); // This works ofc.
```

I need a generic solution. Can someone explain why the `sub.myFunction` does not work? Does anyone have a workaround to solve this?

Comment: Let's ask the other way around: Can you explain why you thought that `'sub.myFunction'` would work?

Comment: I don't think you can use a `[]` to do a double access (accessing `sub` from `myObject` and `myFunction` from `sub`). You may use two `[]`, one for each access.

Comment: *"Can someone explain why the sub.myFunction does not work?"* Because `myObject` doesn't have a property called `sub.myFunction`. It has a property called `sub`, which refers to another object, which has a property called `myFunction`.

Comment: And, by extension: What do you indent to do in the first place? Because the question does not make a lot of sense, i.e. this solves no problem that you should have. If you have that problem, its likely that there's something wrong in your approach itself.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The other question does not really address why a simple string like `"sub.myFunction"` does not work to access the property in js.  I think that's the OP's main question here.

Answer (score 0):

The `.` character is a valid part of a property name in javascript as long as you enclose it in quotes.

What that means to you:

- `myObject["sub.myFunction"]` - looks for a property named `sub.myFunction` on `myObject`.  It does *not* look for a property named `myFunction` on the `sub` property of `myObject`.
- `myObject.sub.myFunction` - does not have the `.` in quotes so it's treated as a property accessor.  That means we look for a `myFunction` property on the `sub` property of `myObject`.